# Detecting phone activity in a class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

So in my Android app, I've been testing how to detect an incoming and outgoing call. I got it to work by building a class that extends a BroadcastReceiver, but in that class if I call another class it crashes. For example MyClass mc = new MyClass(); mc.functionname();

My actual app is running a looping sound clip. I want to pause that sound clip when an incoming or outgoing call is made. The soundclip is played in a class that extends Activity. How do I do this?

This is what I have for the BroadcastReceiver class and my manifest.

```
package com.anthony.phone;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class inComingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(null == bundle)
                return;

        Log.i("MYTAG",bundle.toString());

        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.i("MYTAG","State: "+ state);

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
                String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                Log.i("MYTAG",":) Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);

                String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;

                Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
}
```

and my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.anthony.phone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CallTActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.anthony.phone.inComingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had also this kind of problem. i solved by calling activity from broadcast receiver And writing my class code in particular Activity. As mentioned below

```
            Intent i = new Intent(context,newActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
            context.startActivity(i);
```

i hope it will help you to solve your query.
ask me if you further have any doubt.

Comment: Okay, I thought of this too, but what if my main class is already running the sound. Wouldn't this just run a new activity or will it just send the 'flag' to the running activity that I want?

Comment: yes you can call your running activity from this and by flag you can send a flag using put Extra like below code

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(context, yourActivity.class);  
          i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).putExtra(name, value);  
          context.startActivity(i);

Comment: With the help of put extra you can identify that this call is made from broadcast receiver. so that you can stop your sound clip

Comment: Eh, I'm back at it. I used the above code and all it did was start a new activity. I want to send a string or command to the currently running activity. How do I do that?

Comment: you have to write startActivity(new Intent(newActivity.this, running.class)); and if you have to pass any key then add "put extra(val,val)" to this code

Comment: Is this right? "context.startActivity(new Intent(context, runningActivity.class).putExtra("String","string2")); I'm not sure what you meant by newActivity.this.

Comment: new activity means the activity in which you are at present.